# How to use global dependencies in ES6 import statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, es6-modules

I have Cypress and Percy in a project, so I have `@percy/cypress` as devDep, but I run it only on CI, so each feature branch on staging server pulls ~400MB and doesn't actually use it. Thus, I decided to install this package globally in my Docker image for CircleCI.

However, what can I do with `import '@percy/cypress'` in Cypress' `command.js` file, if the package is global now, rather than in `node_modules`. Is it possible to link '@percy/cypress' to globally installed packaged in order to resolve the import statement?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I applied `npm link`, works like a charm. Plus, I created `install-globals` npm script if someone will need to run CI-like operations locally